# Using JButtons, JLabels, and JTextFields within a JPanel over a painted background

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, paint

I'm pretty new to Java, but have been using `JPanels`, `JButtons`, `JLabels` and `JTextFields` successfully in other parts of my program, but I'm running into trouble when trying to have a `JPanel` with a couple `JButtons`, `JLabels`, and `JTextFields` inside of it overtop of a painted background.

Here is all of the relevant code for this portion of the program.  Currently, when the program runs the only thing that will display is the `p1_fireButton`, `player1PowerField`, and `player1AngleField` overtop of the background (Even though I have the components created for player 2, I purposely commented out adding the `p2_Panel` so that I could concentrate on `p1_Panel`.

The weird thing is that those `JComponents`  will only display if I hit the TAB key after the program is running for whatever reason, which I'm also hoping someone could help me fix.  My goal will be to have the `p1_panel` occupy the left orange box and the `p2_panel` occupy the right orange box. Help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame
{ //start class GameFrame

    ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("background.jpg");
    ImageIcon terrain1 = new ImageIcon("terrain1.png");
    //ImageIcon tank_red = new ImageIcon("tank_red.png");
    //ImageIcon tank_red = new ImageIcon(player1Tank);

    private int x_rectangle = 50;
    private int y_rectangle = 50;

    private JButton p1_fireButton;
    private JButton p2_fireButton;
    private JPanel p1_Panel;
    private JPanel p2_Panel;

    private JLabel player1PowerLabel;
    private static JTextField player1PowerField;
    private JLabel player1AngleLabel;
    private static JTextField player1AngleField;

    private JLabel player2PowerLabel;
    private static JTextField player2PowerField;
    private JLabel player2AngleLabel;
    private static JTextField player2AngleField;

    String player1Name;
    String player2Name;
    final Timer gameTimer = new Timer(8, new timer());

    Projectile projectile = new Projectile(200, 300);

    public GameFrame(String title)
    { //start GameFrame constructor
        super(title);
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 1000;
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(null);
        Color trans = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);

        //player1 panel
        p1_Panel = new JPanel();
        p1_Panel.setLayout(null);
        p1_Panel.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 300);
        p1_Panel.setBackground(trans);

        p2_Panel = new JPanel();
        p2_Panel.setLayout(null);
        p2_Panel.setBounds(500, 0, 500, 300);
        p2_Panel.setBackground(trans);

        //player2 panel
        /*p2_fireButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        p2_fireButtonPanel.setBounds(400, 85, 100, 100);
        p2_fireButtonPanel.setBackground(trans);*/

        //player1 angle/power fields
        player1PowerLabel = new JLabel("Power");
        player1PowerLabel.setLayout(null);
        player1PowerLabel.setBounds(400, 20, 50, 50);

        player1PowerField = new JTextField(3);
        player1PowerField.setLayout(null);
        player1PowerField.setBounds(400, 10, 50, 25);

        player1AngleLabel = new JLabel("Angle");
        player1AngleLabel.setLayout(null);
        player1AngleLabel.setBounds(30, 10, 50, 50);

        player1AngleField = new JTextField(3);
        player1AngleField.setLayout(null);
        player1AngleField.setBounds(300, 10, 50, 25);


        //player2 angle/power fields
        player2PowerLabel = new JLabel("Power");
        player2PowerLabel.setLayout(null);
        player2PowerLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 10, 10);

        player2PowerField = new JTextField(3);
        player2PowerField.setLayout(null);
        player2PowerField.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);

        player2AngleLabel = new JLabel("Angle");
        player2AngleLabel.setLayout(null);
        player2AngleLabel.setBounds(30, 10, 10, 10);

        player2AngleField = new JTextField(3);
        player2AngleField.setLayout(null);
        player2AngleField.setBounds(60, 10, 10, 10);


        //player1 fire button
        p1_fireButton = new JButton("Fire!");
        p1_fireButton.setLayout(null);
        p1_fireButton.setBounds(430, 70, 50, 50);
        ActionListener fireListener = new fireButtonListener();
        p1_fireButton.addActionListener(fireListener);

        //player2 fire button
        p2_fireButton = new JButton("Fire AGAIN!");
        p2_fireButton.setLayout(null);
        p2_fireButton.setBounds(530, 70, 50, 50);


        //add components to player1 panel
        p1_Panel.add(p1_fireButton);
        p1_Panel.add(player1PowerLabel);
        p1_Panel.add(player1PowerField);
        p1_Panel.add(player1AngleLabel);
        p1_Panel.add(player1AngleField);

        //add components to player2 panel
        p2_Panel.add(p2_fireButton);
        p2_Panel.add(player2PowerLabel);
        p2_Panel.add(player2PowerField);
        p2_Panel.add(player2AngleLabel);
        p2_Panel.add(player2AngleField);

        //add components to GameFrame
        add(p1_Panel);
        //add(p2_Panel);

        projectile.fireProjectile(60, -60 * Math.PI / 180.0);

    } //end GameFrame constructor

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Image bg = background.getImage();
        Image t1 = terrain1.getImage();
        Image p1tank = StartPanel.getPlayer1Tank();
        Image p2tank = StartPanel.getPlayer2Tank();
        //Image tank1 = tank_red.getImage();

        g2.drawImage(bg,  0, 0, 1000, 800, this);
        g2.drawImage(t1,  0, 420, 1000, 380, this);


        g2.drawImage(p1tank, 50, 300, 66, 50, null);
        g2.drawImage(p2tank, 500, 300, 66, 50, null);

        player1Name = new String(StartPanel.getPlayer1Name());
        player2Name = new String(StartPanel.getPlayer2Name());

        g.drawString(player1Name, 50, 50);
        g.drawString(player2Name, 525, 50);

        g2.setColor(Color.green);
        g2.fillOval((int)projectile.getXPosition(), (int)projectile.getYPosition(), 15, 15);


    }

    public class timer implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {    
            //TanksGUI.gameFrame.moveRectangle(1, 1);
            projectile.advanceProjectile(0.05);

            if (projectile.getYPosition() > 400)
            {
                gameTimer.stop();
            }
            repaint();

        }

    }
    public class fireButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            gameTimer.start();
        }
    }


} //end class GameFrame
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [BackgroundPanel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) to help you with this. The basic code would be:

```
JPanel north = new JPanel();
north.add( new JLabel(...) );
north.add( new JTextField(10) );
JPanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
BackgroundPanel background = new BackgroundPanel(...);
background.add(north, BorderLayout.North);
background.add(gamePanel);
frame.add(background);
```

The GamePanel is the panel where you do all the custom painting for your game characters. As noted by MadProgrammer, this painting should never be done in the paint() method of the frame.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So, what would I put in the BackgroundPanel class, if all my painting and stuff is in the GamePanel? Because when I do BackgroundPanel background = new BackgroundPanel(); it says the class BackgroundPanel needs to be created. So, I created it, but I'm not sure what I need to put in it. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 2):

- Don't extend from `JFrame` you're not adding any functionality to it that creating an instance couldn't achieve. It also makes you're project unportable.
- Don't override `paint` of top level containers.  If for no other reason they are not double buffered, which will cause you problems if you want to perform animation.  The `paint` chain for a top level container is rather complex and you've just circumvent the whole process.
- Instead, create a custom component (from something like `JPanel`) and use it as you primary canvas.  Override it's `paintComponent` method and render your background to it, making sure you call `super.paintComponent` first.
- Make sure that any containers you are placing on this "canvas" are transparent, otherwise your background won't show up.

Have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more information